# How can I make a timer subtract five minutes when a buton is pressed?

Tags: javascript, time

I'm making a riddle where people have 45 minutes to find the solution, but I want the timer to go down five minutes when they answer incorrectly to prevent them from just guessing the answer. This is what I have for the timer:

```
 function startTimer(duration, display) {
   var start = Date.now(),
     diff,
     minutes,
     seconds;

   function timer() {
     diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

     minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
     seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

     minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
     seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

     display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

     var cat1 = $("input[@name=Verdachte]:checked");


     if (cat1.val() != "2") {
       cat1.val("you are right :)");
       cat1.attr("disabled", true);
       start -= 1000 * 60 * 5;
     }

     if (diff <= 0) {
       start = Date.now() + 1000;
     }
   };

   timer();
   setInterval(timer, 1000);
 }

 window.onload = function() {
   var fortyfiveMinutes = 60 * 45,
     display = document.querySelector('#time');
   startTimer(fortyfiveMinutes, display);
 }
```

But it just keeps subtracting five minutes all the time, so I made a send button for it:

```
$("#results").click(function() {
      if (cat1.val() === "2") {
        cat1.val("you are right :)");
        cat1.attr("disabled", true);
        start -= 1000 * 60 * 5;
      }
    };
```

But now the timer just disappears completely, how can I fix this?

Comment: Is it possible you do a minimal example with JSFiddle?

Comment: Use moment.js. It has a subtract method to subtract whatever you want, minutes, seconds, days, etc..

Comment: I would swear that I have seen this question posted yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

try this , I create a new function to check value and  set varaibles  as globals  to access easy ,and change value of 'start' if value of textbox is wrong

```js
var start = Date.now();

function startTimer(duration, display) {

var diff,
  minutes,
  seconds;

  function timer() {
    diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

    minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
    seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;




    if (diff <= 0) {
      start = Date.now() + 1000;
    }
  };


  timer();
  setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fortyfiveMinutes = 60 * 45,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fortyfiveMinutes, display);
}

function checkValue() {
  var cat1 = $("#Verdachte");

  if (cat1.val() == "2" || cat1.attr("disabled")) {
    cat1.val("you are right :)");
    cat1.attr("disabled", true);
  } else {
    cat1.val("Wrong :(");
    start -= 1000 * 60 * 5;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time"></div>
<input id="Verdachte">
<button onclick="checkValue()"> click me</button>
```